# while reading file of python27 with the python30 i am getting this error

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am getting this error while reading with *python 30* ,this file is generated using *python 27* .

NOTE : this file contains the Chinese characters as string for which i have use code as
   ***string.encode('utf-8')***

please help me to resolve this issue in *python 27* so that i could not get this error while reading *python 27* generated file with *python 30*

```
File "pyang", line 333, in <module>
    run()
File "pyang", line 236, in run
    text = fd.read()
File "C:\Python30\lib\io.py", line 1724, in read
    decoder.decode(self.buffer.read(), final=True))
File "C:\Python30\lib\io.py", line 1295, in decode
    output = self.decoder.decode(input, final=final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode bytes in position 740-741: illegal multibyte sequence
```

what changes we to do in *python 27* in encoding the Chinese character ,so that while decoding this error should not come

Comment: Can you show the relevant code? We can't tell what you're doing, so it's hard to tell what you should do differently.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to read the file in a different encoding than the one you wrote it in.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you're trying to decode using **gbk** CODEC, but you said the file was encoded using UTF-8.

If you are working on the decoding program, change the program to decode as UTF-8 instead of gbk.

If you are working on the generating program, change the program to encode with gbk instead of UTF-8. E.g. `string.encode('gbk')`.

Comment: i can`t change from ***gbk*** to ***UTF-8*** ,its a open source API. Do i can change in my code from ***UTF-8*** to ***gbk***, if yes what is the code  ....thanks